# Private Key storage in Android

Tags: android, certificate, private-key

I have to store the private key of my app in a secure location in the android device, i read about certStore, but it doesnt allow to store a file in it.
Is there any location where I can store it securely and doesn't get deleted if app re-installs.

Comment: are you using that key in application?

Comment: Yes, i receive response from web and decrypt with this key

Comment: so, in this case you have a only option is used shared preference for it, in private mode then only your application can access this shared preference.

Comment: but problem with shared pref is it will be removed when app re-installs. My app uses a registration, and downloads itself after approval.

Comment: Have you tried Android Backup Manager? I think its help you in re-installation of your activity's data. And if this is not you are looking for then you can also try a android application's internal storage.

Comment: ok thank u.  i'm going to try backup manager for shared pref but not sure if it is secure. Can you add your comment as answer so i could accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can store the key in the Preferences of your App. This will protect the key from
getting read by other applications because of the underlying file system restrictions of
the Android system.
```

But this won't protect the key from being read by the user itself.

and if you want to use this shared preference after your application removed and again installed in device then try for Android Backup Manager.
I think its help you in re-installation of your activity's data.

```
EDIT: Android (unfortunately) does not provide a way to do so. The approach I've used
      before is to encrypt this token with another key generated within the app.

      Your app key can be algorithmically generated. This, however, is only as secure as
      your algorithm. Once that is known this is equivalent to storing the token in plain text.
```

Thanks.

Comment: will they be able to access this folder if the phone is rooted?

Comment: Yes, If phone is rooted then they can access this directory.

Comment: but if you write this key in your activity or in a class and once using progaurd or any other security tool once your apk is created then I don't think so anybody easily get it.

Comment: I'm assuming the code cannot be retrieved from the apk since it is compiled. I don't want outside users attacking messages designated for the device. Which is basically why the private key should be protected in the device. Or if the device is in hands of non-user, they should not be able to retrieve the key.

Comment: if you are using the key in your app itself then its best way to put in code, so nobody will retrieve it after compiling the code.

Comment: problem is, there are two apps, 1st one re-installs with the 2nd one, and the key is generated in 1st app, and used by 2nd app